# IE7 z-index issues with jQuery and parent divs (possible stacking context problems)

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7, z-index

I have been wrestling with a IE7 z-index issue today and I can't see to get to the bottom of it. My code below shows a custom styled dropdown menu that is sitting above a div called `wrapper_bottom_outer`, on every other browser other than IE7 the code works to display the select/dropdown class on top of `wrapper_bottom_outer`. However, only on IE7 does `select`/`dropdown` show *behind* the `wrapper_bottom_outer` div.

I've [read up](http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/) today on the problems that developers have with IE7 and z-indexing and i'm certainly experiencing those today.

Is there something obvious that I am missing? Is the problem down to stacking contexts? If so, how do I fix it?

```
<div class="select" style="width: 127px;">
    <dl class="dropdown" style="z-index: 2060; width: 127px;">
        ...content in here...
    </dl>
</div>

<div id="wrapper_bottom_outer" style="z-index: 10;">    
    ...content in here...
    <div id="wrapper_bottom"></div>
</div>

#wrapper_bottom_outer {
    height: 195px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    height: 18px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 12px;
 }

.select {
    position: relative;
}

$("#wrapper_bottom").mouseenter(function(){ 
    $(".select").css('zIndex', '1000');     
    $(".dropdown").css('zIndex', '1001');
    $("#wrapper_bottom_outer").css('zIndex', '1002');
});

$("#wrapper_bottom").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".select").css('zIndex', '2059');
    $(".dropdown").css('zIndex', '2060');
    $("#wrapper_bottom_outer").css('zIndex', '10');
});
```

Comment: What happens when you explicitly give  the dropdown class positioning too - ie .dropdown { position: relative; }

Comment: @McNab I already had a `position: relative;` on the `.dropdown` class. I should have added that to the original post, updated now. It has no affect unfortunately.

Comment: Your parent should be relative, but the child (dropdown) should be "position:absolute"

Comment: @bobek I have set .select to a position of `relative` and .dropdown to a position of `absolute`, but this has no effect on the z-indexing on IE7. The dropdown/select is still showing behind `wrapper_bottom_outer`. The markup is quite extensive, so it would be difficult to put a jsFiddle together for this. I can't see where the issue is with this now. All blog posts, tutorials and comments online suggest that setting the parent's z-index to higher than the child is the fix. I've done that, but still no effect on IE7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're working with Z-index you have to remember that z-index is only applicable to certain positions: relative, absolute, and fixed.

Also, that, besides setting the z-index on the actual element that you want positioned, you also have to add z-index to its parent element.

Give it a try and let us now how it works. If it doesn't creating a jsfiddle would help a lot : http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I have just added a zIndex value to parent div `select`, as you can see in the edited post. That seems to have no affect on any browser. Most of my reading centered around being aware of the parent when setting z-indexes in IE7, but even doing the above makes no difference.

Comment: Notice that I said that z-index only works with specific positions: relative, absolute, and fixed - you don't have anything specified for your classes, you do only for parents.